# Vpn, Proxy и смена ip

Tags: безопасность, ip, proxy, vpn, адрес

Хотелось бы спросить, как я могу настроить браузер (сменить Ip), допустим как будто я в Штатах. Например спортивный канал заблокирован в моей стране, я могу с помощью разных утилит поменять свой ip адрес и всё будет "работать". Но я хочу именно уметь и научиться это делать без всяких тулзов и тд. Вот есть максимум браузер и всё. Посоветуйте информацию где я могу узнать и на примерах поиспользовать и поработать, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Без утилит стандартными средствами Windows, нужно прочитать про: [IKEv2/IPSec](https://nordvpn.com/ru/blog/ikev2ipsec/)
Без утилит в браузере, нужно почитать про: [что такое прокси](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) и [как установить прокси в браузере](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5).

Получить прокси бесплатно можно благодаря `прокси листам`. Вбейте в гугл: `бесплатный прокси лист`, `free proxy list`. В основном сайты показывают страну прокси, скорость и прочую информацию. Найдите подходящий прокси, установите благодаря инструкции выше и смотрите Ваш спорт-канал.

Использование прокси легко обнаружат сайты по типу: `Whoer`, `WhatLeaks` и другие. Лучше использовать VPN. Но это не столь важно для простого просмотра спортивного канала.